# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, wildfly

Application is working on JSF 2.0, WildFly server.
After the user logged in, when the user tries to navigate with the menu, the application throws below exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression cannot be cast to java.lang.String at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.restoreState(BeanValidator.java:451) at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:168) at javax.faces.component.UIInput.restoreState(UIInput.java:1425) at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:379) at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:366) at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138) at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123) at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:591) at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:151) at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353) at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353) at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353) at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.RestorableViewHandler.restoreView(RestorableViewHandler.java:86) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) at com.parsek.medudem.carei.front.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:53) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) at com.parsek.medudem.carei.front.filter.ErrorHandlerFilter.doFilter(ErrorHandlerFilter.java:31) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) at com.parsek.medudem.carei.front.filter.DirectLinkFilter.doFilter(DirectLinkFilter.java:50) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) at com.parsek.vitaly.core.metrics.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:41) at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72) at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80) at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172) at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: How can the application be working if the user gets an error after logging in?

Comment: @kukeltje : it is not giving any exception while user do other thing.when user tries to click specific menu link ,it's show blank page and when I checked console I got exception which I have mentioned above.

Comment: I think issue is with your jsf code. Post the jsp/html page where you are facing this issue

Comment: @Abhijeet: OP should create a [mcve]... not just a jsp/html page. And OP is using facelets, not jsp.

Comment: Sure @Kukeltje. he/she should share MRE